Strange behaviour when using React Native Expo Linking Library. Server URL is not being updated
I am trying to use the React Native Expo Linking Library to define a user's google cloud firestore function endpoint. I have a server URL endpoint for dev mode - localhost:5000 and one for production - my-project.cloudfunctions.net/functions/. I would like to use the Linking library which seems to work asynchronously which may be the reason for it's strange behaviour.  Here is my code:
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
var serverURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
url = Linking.getInitialURL().then(ip => {
    if (ip === 'http://localhost:8081/' || ip === 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/') {
        console.warn("GET LOCAL HOST ADDRESS")
        serverURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
        console.warn(serverURL)
    } else {
        console.warn("GET CLOUD HOST ADDRESS")
        serverURL = 'https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/functions/'
        console.warn(serverURL)
    }
});


module.exports = { serverURL }

When I run the following code in development I get a serverURL of localhost, when I run it in production I get a serverURL of also localhost, even though it executes the CLOUD HOST ADDRESS code segment. Any idea's on what I am doing wrong?

You've exported the original value of serverURL, before it was mutated inside your Promise chain. You should export a function that gets the latest serverURL value or gets the result of the Promise that generated it.

To export a function that accesses the result of the Promise, we would use:
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';

const serverURLPromise = Linking.getInitialURL()
  .then(ip => {
      let serverURL;
    
      if (ip === 'http://localhost:8081/' || ip === 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/') {
          console.warn("GET LOCAL HOST ADDRESS");
          serverURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';
      } else {
          console.warn("GET CLOUD HOST ADDRESS");
          serverURL = 'https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/functions/';
      }
    
      console.warn(serverURL);
      return serverURL;
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error("Could not determine server URL. Defaulting to remote.", err);
      return 'https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/functions/';
  });

const getServerURL = () => serverURLPromise;

module.exports = { getServerURL }

You would consume this elsewhere using:
const serverURL = await getServerURL();

The above would be the recommended path to use, but you do have other options.

Now, if you really wanted to allow the value to be accessed synchronously (without the Promise or using await/then), you could chain to the Promise result and then create a getter function for the resolved value. This allows use outside of your function in a synchronous way.
Note: Using this method, you can still grab the value before it has resolved, so make sure to handle when the value you get back is null gracefully.
You could export this as its own function:
// the resolved value of the above promise.
// As we don't know it's value yet, we'll initialise it as null.
let resolvedValue = null;

// update our reference to the value once it is known
serverURLPromise.then(url => { resolvedValue = url; });

const getServerURLIfKnown = () => resolvedValue;

// updated module.exports
module.exports = { getServerURL, getServerURLIfKnown }

This would be used like so:
const serverURL = getServerURLIfKnown();

if (serverURL) {
  // do something with URL
} else {
  // server URL not yet resolved.
  getServerURL().then(url => {
    // do something with URL
  });
}

Or, you could attach the getter to the getServerURL function that we exported as
a property of it.
// the resolved value of the above promise.
// As we don't know it's value yet, we'll initialise it as null.
let resolvedValue = null;

// update our reference to the value once it is known
serverURLPromise.then(url => { resolvedValue = url; });

// attach read-only "cached" property with resolved value
Object.defineProperty(getServerURL, "cached", {
  get: () => resolvedValue;
});

module.exports = { getServerURL }

Now you can get the value synchronously when it's known using:
const serverURL = getServerURL.cached;

if (serverURL) {
  // do something with URL
} else {
  // server URL not yet resolved.
  getServerURL().then(url => {
    // do something with URL
  });
}

